# Spring Boot: configuration does not load correctly my password variable from application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I'm facing a problem using Spring Boot configurations:

My configuration is not loaded correctly for all of my parameters.

I'm using a profile (in my case 'qualif') with application-qualif.yml configuration file but values from it are not overwriting application.yml values. This behaviour is expected.

Also i'm using Lombok.

My application.yml here:

```yaml
mail:
  login:    'login'
  address:  'login@email.com'
  password: 'myRealPassword'
```

My application-qualif.yml here:

```yaml
spring:
  otherValues: ...
```

My configuration here:

```java
@Configuration
@Getter
public class SmtpConfiguration {
    @Value("${mail.login}")
    private String login;

    @Value("${mail.address}")
    private String address;

    @Value("${mail.password}")
    private String password;
}
```

When I try to display password it always return me '123456' but I can't find any reference of '123456' in my project. It's expected to be **myRealPassword** here.

```java
log.printf(Level.INFO, "Mail password: " + smtpConfiguration.getPassword());
```

Other values from smtpConfiguration return same value from application.yml

```
2021-08-19 10:55:26.102 INFO  192494 --- [   scheduling-1] x.x.x.x.x.x.XXXScheduledTask: 
Attempt to send mail using login@email.com with password 123456
```

Console output:

```
2021-08-19 10:48:49.572 INFO  192412 --- [   scheduling-1] x.x.x.x.x.x.XXXService: 
Mail password: 123456
```

This code is run under Linux env and it's working on my local computer (Windows) using no profiles.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: I dont think program can just randomly create a string "123456" for you. Try to evaluate in debug something like this: ApplicationContext#getEnvironment#getValue("mail.password"). Also you can try to refactor your code to use setter injection with @Value and try to debug where this value comes from using stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

It seems that linux env variable named MAIL_PASSWORD exists and equals to '123456'.

I didn't know this was overwriting YAML values if the configuration does not specified it like:

```yaml
mail:
  password: ${mail.password}
```